# DNN Theme. How to populate DropDownList values from a setting?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I have been working on a DNN theme for several clients.
The theme has a DropDownList and its values ​​are different for each client. I do not want to create many themes (one per client) because the DropDownList values ​​are the only difference between them.

How can I fill in the DropDownList values ​​based on some theme configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement this behivor on my theme I use *DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config* class.

- First I create an App Setting in the dnn web.config.

You can do this manually:
    `<add key="DropDownListValues" value="Value1,Value2,Value3" />`

...or you can add these values from code:

```
public static void AddAppSetting(string name, string value)
    {
        var xmlDocument = DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.AddAppSetting(DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.Load(), name, value);
        DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.Save(xmlDocument);

    }
```

- Having this property you can always populate your DropDownList this way:

  ```
      var stylesCommaSeparated = DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Config.GetSetting("DropDownListValues");
      stylesCommaSeparated.Split(',').ForEach(setting=>DropDownList1.Items.Add(setting));
  ```

Comment: Very interesting approach - but be advised that using the `AddAppSetting` function  - each save would trigger an application pool recycle.  Which could be an issue depending on how you use it and who's adding settings.